# Group By is giving me a rough go with these subqueries

Tags: sql, sql-server

Below is my query. I'm having issues with the group by clause and these subqueries. I'll post desired results below query. I've tried splitting the first subquery into to subquerys but that is given me even more problems. If anyone can help would be much appreciated. Even if I have to go a different route to achieve it.

```
DECLARE
@iHostID int=NULL,
@iTrips int=6

DECLARE
@vTripcount int,
@vStartDate datetime,
@vHostID int,
@vTrips int;


SELECT 
@vHostID=@iHostID,
@vTrips=@iTrips;


SELECT
  PlayerID, 
  TripNumber,
  GamingDate,
  TWin,
  TAVG
  FROM
    (
    SELECT
    PlayerID,
    GamingDate,
    TWin,
    SUM(TWin) / COUNT(PlayerID) AS TAVG,
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY PlayerID ORDER BY GamingDate desc) AS TripNumber
  FROM 
   (
    SELECT DISTINCT 
    PlayerID,
    GamingDate,
    TWin
    FROM dbo.CDS_STATDAY sd (NOLOCK) 
    WHERE IDType='P'    
  )sd

      INNER JOIN CDS_PLAYER p ON p.Player_ID=sd.PlayerID
  WHERE
      (@vHostID IS NULL OR p.HostUser_ID=@vHostID)

    )b

 WHERE
  TripNumber <= @iTrips

 GROUP BY PlayerID
```

Currently I am getting this,

```
+------------------------------------------+
| PlayerID    TripNumber  GamingDate  TWin |
+------------------------------------------+
| 7            1        6/1/2012    0.5    |
| 8            1        2/28/2014  2.325   |
| 8            2        1/29/2014   1.5    |
| 8            3        1/26/2014   2.4    |
| 8            4        1/24/2014   1.2    |
| 8            5        1/19/2014   5.25   |
| 8            6        1/15/2014  10.2294 |
| 9            1        12/29/2016  33.84  |
+------------------------------------------+
```

Want something more like this,

```
+---------+----------+
|PlayerId |result    |
+---------+----------+
|7        |0.500000  |
|8        |3.817400  |
|9        |33.840000 |
+---------+----------+
```

Thanks!

Comment: It should be noted that the first result table is what I was getting before trying to add, SUM(TWIN) / COUNT(PlayerID) as TAVG and the GROUP BY clause

Comment: So if you want just 2 fields (playerId and results) why do you select 4 fields? that's one issue!!

Comment: Good point. This was an old query pull that came to me to fix and I just got  thrown into the sql ocean and am learning as fast as possible. A lot of little things like that slip by me because I haven't had a lot of experience with it. I assume it selects those fields because calcs are being done based on the selected fields from within the subqueries.

Comment: `SELECT PlayerID, result = AVG(TWin) FROM (SELECT PlayerID, GamingDate, TWin, RN = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY PlayerID ORDER BY GamingDate DESC) FROM dbo.CDS_STATDAY WHERE IDType = 'P' GROUP BY PlayerID, GamingDate, TWin) AS T WHERE RN <= @iTrips GROUP BY PlayerID;`

Comment: @ZLK I'm double checking but I think this may work!!! Only thing I'm worried about is, I was mapping player ID's here, INNER JOIN CDS_PLAYER p ON p.Player_ID=sd.PlayerID
  WHERE
      (@vHostID IS NULL OR p.HostUser_ID=@vHostID)  How can I get this to still function or do I not need it?

Comment: If playerID is unique in the CDS_PLAYER table, it shouldn't matter if you just add it into the subquery (or even just join it to T or put an `EXISTS` clause in or whatever, there's a whole bunch of ways you can do it).

Comment: @ZLK thanks so much. I've been trying to get over that hump for a few days now. Very insightful. Appreciate your time!